# integrating xampp to run Java Bridge applications

Tags: java, php, tomcat, xampp, php-java-bridge

I installed the PHP/Java Bridge and it's running successfully in the Tomcat port 8080. But when I'm running my PHP files in Tomcat, it gives me many errors.
Those errors are not coming when I run it in XAMPP. Is it possible to run an application in XAMPP and use Java Bridge?

Errors:

> Warning: require_once(http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\xampp\xampp\xampp\htdocs\gg.php on line 1
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\xampp\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\xampp\xampp\htdocs\gg.php on line 1

Comment: It would be better if you mention your error (stack trace) in the question.